# Javascript: Count occurrences of array in string variable and return length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

```
var search = ["ab", "cd", "ef"];
var string = "ab yz cd wx ef uv ab yz cd";
```

I'd like to create a function that can take in the search terms and find how many of them occur in the string, then have the output be something like:

```
[{"ab": 2}, {"cd": 2}, {"ef": 1}]
```

I could do this with a single array, but for now I have 2 separate arrays  I need to work with. Any ideas would help! I'm thinking I want to split the string, but don't know how to search using the text in the 'search' variable to count what's in the split string.

Comment: This question again. Is this like some kind of test that everyone has to do these days or something. This question gets asked every other hour

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this problem yourself? What have you gotten stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `search` array and return an object for every items in the array as keys and its values the respective occurrence length in the `string`:

```js
var search = ["ab", "cd", "ef"],
    string = "ab yz cd wx ef uv ab yz cd",
    result = search.map(function (item) {
      return {
        [item]: string.split(item).length - 1
      };
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with a [word boundary regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```js
var search = ["ab", "cd", "ef"];
var string = "ab yz cd wx ef uv ab yz cd";

console.log(
  // iterate over the array
  search.map(function(v) {
    // initialize object for array element
    var obj = {};
    // define array element as the number of count
    // regex can be generate from string using RegExp 
    // constructor and use modifrier `g` for global match
    obj[v] = string.match(new RegExp('\\b' + v + '\\b', 'g')).length;
    // return the object
    return obj;
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [`create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) an empty object, iterate `search` and initialize the wanted items in the object with zero.

Then [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) `string` and count only items which keys are [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) the object.

```js
var search = ["ab", "cd", "ef"],
    string = "ab yz cd wx ef uv ab yz cd",
    count = Object.create(null);

search.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a] = 0;
});

string.split(' ').forEach(function (a) {
    a in count && count[a]++;
});

console.log(count);
```